# How to drop the imaginary part from numbers such as x + 0.0i in R

Tags: r

I guess this will be already answered somewhere, so apologies in advance, but I tried to search without luck, so.....

....What is the smart way to deal with numbers of the form x + 0.0i in R ?

For example suppose we have

```
y <- 1 + 0.0i
```

So of course:

```
y == 1
```

is true. So what is the best way to coerce y to be 1.

**Edit:**

I don't want to discard the imaginary part unless `round(Im(y)) == 0` but I was hoping for a way to avoid having to explicitly test for this.

Comment: Thanks @joran but that discards the imaginary part even if it is not zero, doesn't it ?

Comment: Hmm, do you mean you want to drop the imaginary bit **only** if it is zero?

Comment: @JoeKing That definitely wasn't clear from your question. I suspect you're going to be stuck writing a function that checks the imaginary part.

Comment: @GavinSimpson yes, that's right. I'm sorry, that in hindsight I realise I didn't explain this well in my OP, so I have edited it now.

Comment: @joran yes, I am deeply sorry about that ! I should have made that clear in my OP and I have now edited the Q to reflect that.

Comment: @BenBolker thanks, that's really helpful. I love how I almost always learn something new on this website, every time I post a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't think of anything better than this (yes, it's surprising there's not a built-in imaginary-squashing feature ... or maybe someone will yet come up with one)

```
f <- function(x) {
   if (all(Im(z <- zapsmall(x))==0)) as.numeric(z) else x
}
```

Comment: This is great - may I ask: why do you need the `all()` ?

Comment: because `if` requires a single criterion.  More specifically, suppose I pass this function a length-2 complex vector `x` where `Im(x[1])` is (close to) zero but `Im(x[2])` is not; then I shouldn't do any zapping or setting to `numeric`, because the whole vector will still be complex.