# Convert imaginary to real number in R

Tags: r

I've got a .csv and an .xlsx version of a data set that I'm importing, and no matter what I do, my real numbers from the document get imported either as imaginary or as scientific notation that I cannot get rid of. I tried `options(scipen = 999)` and also tried the function

```
f <- function(x) {
  if (all(Im(z <- zapsmall(x))==0)) as.numeric(z) else x
}
```

that I saw here: [How to drop the imaginary part from numbers such as x + 0.0i in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520188/how-to-drop-the-imaginary-part-from-numbers-such-as-x-0-0i-in-r)

Nothing seems to change. Tried that both when uploading the .csv version and the .xlsx version. Any ideas how to get rid of these?

Here's some data to play with:

```
structure(list(GABA_Area = c(0.00064604+0i, 0.001132496+0i, -0.000143955+0i, 
0.000874619+0i, 0.000654323+0i, 0.000807692+0i, 0.000415511+0i
), GABA_ConcCr = c(0.137742432+0i, 0.153683294+0i, -0.004261154+0i, 
0.134065319+0i, 0.117744826+0i, 0.12347494+0i, 0.08741057+0i), 
    GABA_ConcCho = c(0.14852694+0i, 0.211853026+0i, 0.008788317+0i, 
    0.176029256+0i, 0.147270858+0i, 0.214000954+0i, 0.091670108+0i
    ), GABA_ConcNAA = c(0.081673683+0i, 0.094836052+0i, 0.030840143+0i, 
    0.092618293+0i, 0.069915052+0i, 0.082425039+0i, 0.059673271+0i
    )), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

EDIT:
Here's another example:

```
dput(OLD_data[1:30,3])
c(0.00064604+0i, 0.001132496+0i, -0.000143955+0i, 0.000874619+0i, 
0.000654323+0i, 0.000807692+0i, 0.000415511+0i, 0.000801348+0i, 
0.00083489+0i, 0.001086424+0i, 0.000574472+0i, 0.000898015+0i, 
0.000506014+0i, 0.000941727+0i, -0.021617815+0i, 0.000786799+0i, 
-0.000864898+0i, 0.00098191+0i, 0+0.0000798079424579433i, 0.000971948+0i, 
-0.042977607+0i, 0.000849911+0i, 0.00054918+0i, 0.000926088+0i, 
0.000622691+0i, 0.000647898+0i, 0.001010186+0i, 0+0.0179001356679363i, 
-0.064823706+0i, 0.000912678+0i)
```

In this case, when I do `lapply(data,f)` and save it into `reals`, I get:

```
dput(reals)
list(0.00064604, 0.001132496, -0.000143955, 0.000874619, 0.000654323, 
    0.000807692, 0.000415511, 0.000801348, 0.00083489, 0.001086424, 
    0.000574472, 0.000898015, 0.000506014, 0.000941727, -0.021617815, 
    0.000786799, -0.000864898, 0.00098191, 0+0.0000798079424579433i, 
    0.000971948, -0.04297761, 0.000849911, 0.00054918, 0.000926088, 
    0.000622691, 0.000647898, 0.001010186, 0+0.0179001356679363i, 
    -0.06482371, 0.000912678)
```

My goal is to account for both the real and the imaginary part. I get it that when imag is 0, it is dropped but in a couple of cases it's not, and it seems for those the function doesn't work.

In terms of how my data looks like in Excel, the xlsx is displayed as rational numbers only (the way I want it). The .csv shows up the same way. Pretty sure the problem is there, yes. But Excel is temperamental and it seems easier to correct it in R. I also have many of these files.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried?  The function you found works so it's not clear how you're trying to use it - i.e. you should be iterating over your columns with `lapply(dat, f)` That said, this should probably be addressed at import rather than fixed post.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); dat |> mutate(across(where(is.complex), f))`

Comment: Hi there, I was using it the wrong way, indeed, trying to do ```f(data)```. However, now with ```lapply(data,f)``` it only works whenever the imaginary part is 0. Which is not what I want. Any ideas how to make it account for a non-zero imaginary part?

Comment: You can use `Re()` to return only the real part of the number.

Comment: I'm not sure that solves it, as in a couple of cases the real part is 0, but the imaginary isn't. And ```lapply(data,f)``` already gives 0s to such cases.

Comment: Can you update your example to be more reflective of what you have and include your expected output?

Comment: Updated. See above.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution - an easier way in your case where your numbers only have a real or imaginary part and the other part is zero is to just add the parts together `Re(x) + Im(x)`.

Comment: Could you give me an example how you'd apply that please?

Comment: Using dplyr, `dat |> mutate(across(where(is.complex), \(x) Re(x) + Im(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Right, I found a silly way around it. I converted the columns to character, then removed the `0+`, `i` and `+0` symbols, which meant I removed either the imaginary, or the real number, whenever one of them was 0. Then I recoded back to numeric:

```
data$GABA_Area <-gsub("i","",as.character(data$GABA_Area))
data$GABA_Area <-gsub("[+]0$","",as.character(data$GABA_Area))
data$GABA_Area <-gsub("^0[+]","",as.character(data$GABA_Area))
data$GABA_Area <-as.numeric(data$GABA_Area)
```

Certainly not a very smart approach but does the job in my case. Thanks everyone for the helpful input!